# List ID column data object size

Tags: list

Can anyone tell me what type of Integer the LIST ID column is on a list?

We're using a list to store data records that we refresh the entire set every 12 hours. It's about 4500 rows so I will eat up 9000 IDs a day.

Want to make sure that column won't explode! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MSDN [SPListItem.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id.aspx) is an [32 bit integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/td2s409d), which should be capable of holding values up to **[2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/system.int32.maxvalue)**.

```
(2147483647 / 9000) * 1 day = 653.291 years
```

Comment: Actually ID starts on 1 and not 0 so it might actually be 2147483646, unless it's actually saved as ID-1 and presented / referenced otherwise

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for finging that. I had looked, but couldn't put my finger on it!